# Storing a HashMap with OrmLite

Tags: android, listview, ormlite

I have a class `ShoppingList` with the following `Map`:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
Map<Category, List<Product>> products;
```

Then, on a `Fragment`, I have a ListView that should show all `Categories`. Therefore, I set the `Adapter` for it with the following code:

```
aisles.setAdapter(new ShoppingListEditAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Category>(mShoppingList.getMap().keySet())));
```

By default it should be empty. If I click a button, a Dialog opens, and there I input the text for the new category or aisle that I want to create. Thus, I run the following code:

```
Category category = new Category();
category.setName(editText.getText().toString());
mShoppingList.getMap().put(category, new ArrayList<Product>());
try {
    helper.getShoppingListDao().update(mShoppingList);
    ((BaseAdapter) aisles.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should modify the `ShoppingList` I have for this Fragment, adding a Category to the `Map`. However, even if I call `notifyDatasetChanged()` for my Adapter or restart the application, the `ListView` doesn't get populated with the data. Both `Category` and `Product` are `Serializable`. Why doesn't it get populated?

Comment: If I run `mShoppingList.getMap().put(new Category("Congelados"), new ArrayList<Product>());` just before creating the `Adapter`, it does show.

Comment: It can be fixed by setting the Adapter again when the Dialog is accepted by resetting the Adapter, and then it shows. However, they are still not persisted.

Comment: This is because the keyset object that you populate the adapter with does not get updated automatically when you update the map object. That's why setting it a second time around, as you've done here, works. As for fixing it: I'd recommend making an Adapter that can accept a Map directly. Or you can stick with your present solution, as it's getting the job done. 

edit: this was meant as a reply to your posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In keeping with what I've posted as a comment, here is a simple adapter that will accept a Map and display the keys of the map as the values of the list. I've not tested it in accordance with the actual item id's, but for displaying a map that will be mutated, it seems to work (i.e. if the map itself is changed and notifyDataSetChanged() is called, it will work). I've counted on ArrayAdapter to do the heavy lifting and just overrode the methods I wanted.

The obvious downside is I'm not sure how expensive it is to call keySet().toArray() but I imagine it's a linear time operation, beyond the extra memory usage. But basically I don't know a great way to get around this issue, as it relies on taking a Set into some sort of ordered collection.

```
    public class MapAdapter<K, V> extends ArrayAdapter<K> {

    private Map<K, V> items;

    public MapAdapter(Context context, int resource, Map<K,V> items) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public K getItem(int position) {
        return ((K []) items.keySet().toArray())[position];
    }

}
```

Comment: Given how expensive I think doing a toArray() call every time there, and how I can't think of a way of only doing it when the items map itself has been updated (generating an indexed collection that is), I'd recommend not using this but rather manually updating the Adapter yourself each time.

Comment: It still doesn't save the objects into the database. It shows it until you go out of the fragment.

Comment: Hey since this is a slightly different issue, could you post the state of your code now? Not sure what exactly you have so I can't really answer this.